# List of dicts in Python with Redis

Tags: python, json, redis

I am currently keeping my quote-unquote "database" of my Python web-app in JSON file, but I need to migrate onto Redis. How would I create the following datastructure in Python-Redis?

```
[
    {
        "username": "guest1",
        "password": "foo",
        "enabled": true,
        "__comment__": "Alice"
    },
    {
        "username": "guest2",
        "password": "bar",
        "enabled": false,
        "__comment__": "Bob"
    },
    {
        "username": "guest3",
        "password": "baz",
        "enabled": false,
        "__comment__": "Charlie"
    }
]
```

I thought of using hash maps or storing JSON, but I have no idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/) and [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/json/).

You can store JSON objects and perform JSON operations on JSON objects. If your objects are simple like in the example, you can also use [HASHes](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/hashes/) to store simple dictionary like objects.

If you need to perform searches over your database, `RediSearch` has the capabilities for that. It can handle both hashes and JSON keys.

All the capabilities I mentioned are also available with [redis-py](https://redis.io/docs/clients/python/) client, so migrating the data should not be too complex

**Using redis-py:**

```py
from redis import Redis
from redis.commands.json.path import Path

conn = Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)

Keys = [
    {
        "username": "guest1",
        "password": "foo",
        "enabled": true,
        "__comment__": "Alice"
    },
    {
        "username": "guest2",
        "password": "bar",
        "enabled": false,
        "__comment__": "Bob"
    },
    {
        "username": "guest3",
        "password": "baz",
        "enabled": false,
        "__comment__": "Charlie"
    }
]

# using JSON
for id, mapping in enumerate(keys):
    conn.json().set(f"json:{id}", Path.root_path(), mapping)

# using HASH
for id, mapping in enumerate(keys):
    conn.hset(f"hash:{id}", mapping=mapping)

# Getting the objects back

j = conn.json().get("json:1")
h = conn.hgetall("hash:1")
```

Comment: I'm having problems with saving it, could you please give an example?
When I try it, I end up somehow with mulitply nested arrays.

Comment: No problem. With JSON? Do you want each object in the list as a separate object?

Comment: Nah, I need it all in one object, because I have three of these "databases" each with different purpose.

Comment: I can add such example later. A common design is to have different prefix for different keys, and this way you can also index specific prefixes with different indexes

Comment: Thanks an awful lot! Could you also add an example for recreating this very structure from Redis? (Cuz I'm too dumb)

Comment: conn.json().get('json:1')